# Zaphoyd websocketpp and wss (TLS) Client Example

Tags: c++, ssl, wss, websocket++

I have need for fast, secure and portable websockts so I have been digging around the internet and I came across WebSocket++ by [Zaphoyd Studios](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) .

I have zero c++ experience (I am a proficient programmer though) but it seems to tick every box I require and I quickly adapted the echo_server and telemetry_client examples up at [github](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) and put together a proof of concept.

Setting my hand to the wss server example (echo_server_tls) I quickly compiled and used a simple test client to verify it was working.

Unfortunately, there is where my inexperience fails me, I was naively hoping that changing the url to wss and including the tls enabled client header (asio_client.hpp not asio_no_tls_client.hpp) would set me off in the right direction!

It does not, instead it gives the error;-

```
[2014-05-29 01:17:58] [application] Get Connection Error: endpoint not secure
```

So... my question;-

Does anyone have a "echo_client_tls" example as it were to get me headed in the correct direction, I very much doubt that I am the first to do this (perhaps just the most inexperienced with c++ though).

I am sure I can take it from there (I will even submit it back to git as it would probably be useful for other noobs such as my self).

P.S. Kudos to the authors if they ever read this, it seems a very complete implementation!

Comment: I am finding more answers to my own questions as I go on, I have found this example most informative;-

https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/c5b5492e5ce16bd7ab2ae5f37ef432d12437aa98/examples/debug_client/debug_client.cpp

Help would still be appreciated.

Comment: did you get it resolved? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Never did get an example, in the end I went to python instead.

Answer (score 5):

On top of including the tls enabled client header, the client would need to provide a handler for `tls_init`. You can modify one of the existing client examples to support tls by adding the following handler.

```
_client.set_tls_init_handler([this](websocketpp::connection_hdl){
    return websocketpp::lib::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. I now have a wss client working.